# How to drop columns with mode occurences over 95% in python

Tags: python

```
for i in X_Cat.columns:
  if(X_Cat[i].mode().count()/X_Cat[i].count()>perc):
     X_Cat.drop(i,axis=1,inplace=True)
print(X_Cat.columns)
```

My code doesn't successfully drop the columns. I need to drop columns with mode occurences over 95%.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```py
X_Cat.loc[
    :,
    X_Cat.apply(lambda x: not ((x.value_counts()/ x.count()).iloc[0]> 0.95))]
```